# Compiling with TeXmaker: error

Tags: errors, texmaker, compilation-error

What does TeXmaker mean by 'I can't file' when compiling lines of code?

```
\begin{titlepage}
\title{\huge\bfseries{ZIBSIP Mathematics Content Module 101}}
\author{JMM Sensele}
\date{\today} 
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: Please show a small but compiling document to allow us to recreate your problem. Please also give use the complete error message from the log file, no the shortened version texmaker shows you.

Comment: Please also choose a more descriptive title for your post,  `Compiling with TeXmaker: error` is crap because there are thousands of posts about problems with texstudio.